# kill bash loop executed from command line

Tags: bash, command-line

I run my command in a loop. I wrote the loop directly to a bash command line:

```
$ while true; do mycommand; done
```

`mycommand` is a command doing a lot of io and waiting for events so it does not consume much processor time.

How can I interrupt the loop? When I press `ctrl-c` or `ctrl-\` then mycommand is terminated but it is started again immediately. When I log in to another terminal and kill the command then the situation is the same.

Is it possible to interrupt the loop without killing the terminal session?

Comment: A lot of times if you just hold down `ctrl-c` it'll end up getting the loop eventually

Comment: just `kill -9 %%`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple enough way to kill loops started interactively would be to stop the command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>), which should print a job number, say `[2]+  Stopped`, which you can then kill using `kill %2`.

Answer (score 1):

You want ps -f. pstree also is very useful. Have a look at the PPID (parent PID).

```
$ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
rui       7725  7722  0 13:30 pts/0    00:00:01 -bash
rui       8062  7725  0 14:09 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
```

$pstree -g

├─starter(1600)───charon(1603)─┬─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              ├─{charon}(1603)
        │                              └─{charon}(1603)

Comment: why does the asker want this?

Answer (score 1):

A little background:

Your command `mycommand` doesn't resend SIGINT when it receives one, and just terminates instead. Because of this, `bash` instance running the loop cannot determine that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> was used to terminate execution, and assumes it was just a keyboard shortcut you issued for `mycommand`. Since it would be undesirable to terminate your shell because of a keyboard shortcut (imagine using `vi` for instance), `bash` just goes on and executes another loop iteration.

The ultimate solution would be to fix `mycommand`, so that it kills itself with SIGINT when it receives one, letting `bash` know it should stop as well.

```
void sigint_handler(int sig)
{
    // Execute your normal handler
    signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL); // don't catch the signal anymore
    kill(getpid(), SIGINT); // kill itself with the same signal
}
```

Source: http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html

If you cannot fix `mycommand`, you'll have to either close the terminal session, or kill the `bash` process which does the looping and the current instance of `mycommand`, in that order.